# Why in protected mode inheritance upcasting is not working

Tags: c++

When i am inheriting class in protected mode why `Derived* to Base*` is failing

```
class Base { };

class Derived : protected Base { };

int main()
{
   Base* b = new Derived(); // compile error
}
```

Comment: Because it is not `public` inheritance... Stuff inherited in `protected` mode will be accessible only for derived and friend classes.

Comment: The inheritance relationship is only visible within derived.

Comment: Public inheritance represents an `is-a` relationship.  Protected and private inheritance represents a `is-secretly-a-shhh-don't-tell-anyone` relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Access to the baseclasses is the same as access to any member. From the outside, access is simply forbidden. Only privileged code (code that can access other protected or even private parts) can access the baseclass in that way.

Comment: Derived class functions can access the protected members of the base class right?